# How to create slider with one infinite slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, infinite-loop

I want to implement slider with the same slide and dont know how to loop it. This how should slider look, 3 slider, 3slides to show, just changing their position by click on arrow

[image]

Seems like any library provides this functionality, and got no idea how create it with vanilla js.

Comment: need to show three image and on button click it should change the position?

Comment: @Akash yes, just like on the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it's not easy but I already get this problem. I post you the code I do to patch this.

```
// Get all the images from your slider in an array
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

// Duplicates existing slides at the end of the slider
const firstSlideClone = slides[0].cloneNode(true);
const lastSlideClone = slides[slides.length - 1].cloneNode(true);
slider.appendChild(firstSlideClone);
slider.insertBefore(lastSlideClone, slides[0]);

// Initialize the counter that follows the current position of the slider
let slidePosition = 1; // start with the second slide, avoiding the clone of the first slide

// Function that moves to the next slide
function nextSlide() {
  // Hide the current slide
  slides[slidePosition - 1].classList.remove('active');

  // Increments the position counter
  slidePosition++;

  // If we reach the end of the slider, go to the first duplicate slide
  if (slidePosition === slides.length - 1) {
    slidePosition = 1;
  }

  // Show next slide
  slides[slidePosition - 1].classList.add('active');
}
```

I tried to comment it for you so that you understand each line a little. Normally you just have to adapt it to your own code

Comment: Thank you my friend, but is there any idea how to do this with react?

Comment: I'm not a pro ReactJS developer. Ask this to Chat GPT he probably can help you i think to convert the code!